# Scraping Financial Tables From Web Page with R, rvest,Rcurl

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying parsing financial tables from web page. I proceeded. But I am not able to arrange list, or data.frame

```
library(rvest)
link <- "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/garan/financials/balance-sheet/quarter"
read <- read_html(link)
prs <- html_nodes(read, ".financials")
irre <- html_text(prs)
re <- strsplit(irre, split = "\r\n")
```

`re` is something like this:

[27] "Assets"
 [28] ""
 [29] "    "
 [30] "        "
 [31] "             All values TRY millions."
 [32] "            31-Dec-201431-Mar-201530-Jun-201530-Sep-201531-Dec-2015"
 [33] "            5-qtr trend"
 [34] "        "
 [35] "    "
 [36] "    "
 [37] "        "
 [38] "             Total Cash & Due from Banks"
 [39] "            27.26B26.27B26.7B34.51B27.9B"
 [40] "        "
 [41] "        "
 bla bla...

How Can I edit this list through data.frame that properly like this [page](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/garan/financials/balance-sheet/quarter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(XML)

theurl <- "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/garan/financials/balance-sheet/quarter"
re <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
```

The result is a list with two dataframes.